# Using fs.stat and fs.writeFile

Tags: node.js, fs

I need to check for the existence of a file before executing `fs.writeFile`, so if the file already exists, `fs.writeFile` sould not replace the file. But the documentation says the following :

> Using `fs.stat()` to check for the existence of a file before calling `fs.open()`, `fs.readFile()` or `fs.writeFile()` is not recommended. Instead, user code should open/read/write the file directly and handle the error raised if the file is not available.

If I call `fs.writeFile` directly, the function will replace the file if it already exists, and the `error` variable will be `null`.

I want to ignore the call to `fs.writeFile` if the file already exists.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to ignore the call to `fs.writeFile` if the file already exists.

Use the `wx` flag (documented [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback)):

> `wx` - Like `'w'` but fails if path exists.

```
fs.writeFile('/path/to/file', data, { flag : 'wx' }, function(err) {
  if (err && err.code === 'EEXIST') {
    console.log('file already exists, not overwriting');
    return;
  }
  ...
})
```

**EDIT**: the reason it's not recommended to use `fs.stat` before `fs.open/fs.writeFile/fs.readFile` is because of an inherent race condition: in between the calls to `fs.stat` and (say) `fs.writeFile`, there's a small window of time in which a file *could* get created, even though it didn't yet exist when `fs.stat` was called. So there would still be a chance that `fs.writeFile` could overwrite an existing file.

If you use file flags, the check for existence is done atomically.

Answer (score 2):

Robert has the correct answer (just pass in the appropriate flags `fs.writeFile(fname, data, { flag : 'wx' }, ...)`), but I thought I would explain why it is not recommended to use `fs.stat()` followed by `fs.writeFile()`.  When you do something like this:

```
fs.stat(fname, function(err) {
    if (err) {
       // in the bit of time right here, there is a race condition
       fs.writeFile(fname, data, function(err) {
           // file written
       });
    }
});
```

There is a race condition.  In any sort of multi-process system or any sort of file system shared with other systems, there can be a situation where `fs.stat()` reports the file is not there, but between that moment and the time that you actually call `fs.writeFile()`, some other process or thread or computer writes that file and now you've just overwritten an existing file which is something you did not want to do.  So, this is simply not reliable in some circumstances and thus is not recommended.

What you need instead is an atomic operation that will both check if it's there and, if not, will create it for you.  That will give you a reliable system so that the file will never be accidentally overwritten.

By passing the `wx` flags to `fs.writeFile()`, you tell the underlying OS to write these bytes to the file only if the file doesn't already exist and it will be done in an atomic fashion that does not have multi-thread/process/computer race conditions.

---

There are limits to the race condition and there are situations where your system would not actually be subject to it (only one node.js process that can ever write to that file), but it is simply safer to just always code in the safe way, no matter what and, in fact, the safe way is less code too.

Comment: I guess we both had the feeling this deserved some more explanation :D

Comment: @robertklep - Yeah, the OP mentioned in comments they didn't understand the reason and your answer (which I upvoted) did not contain that explanation at the time I wrote this.

Comment: Yes, I realized too that it would be a good thing to point out _why_ it's not recommended :)

Comment: @hdunn - you don't seem to understand the race condition that can occur between the two api calls.

Comment: @jfriend00 - OK with your nice explanation I was wrong and delete my previous comment. Thanks for making me re-think about it, cheers.